# Given an equation with coefficients a and b, how can I find the values a and b for which the equation has 1 solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given system of equations: {x+ay=1, x-ay=b} where x,y are variables and a,b parameters.

My idea was that I should write the system of equations as a reduced echelon matrix, but it doesn't seem to work instead I did this.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & a & 1 \\
    1 & -a & b \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

~ $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & (1+b)/2 \\
    0 & a & (b-1) \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

And this is where I get uncertain. My idea is that if a = 0 and b-1≠0 we should not have any solution to the system. if a = 0 and b-1=0 we should have an infinite amount of solutions and else we should have one solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple criterion for the existence of solutions:

> A non-homogeneous linear system of equations $A \mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has solutions if & only if  the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $A\mathbf b$have the same rank.
>
> Furthermore, this common rank is the *codimension* of the affine subspace of solutions.